# Coldfusion CFMAIL - Trying to rename attachment so it doesn't look like a virus

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I have been trying to rename the file attachment for some time and cannot figure it out. Am running CF10 ad have tried this:

```
<cfmail from="#fromAddress#" 
    to="#trim(toAddress)#" 
    subject="#trim(subject)#"
    type="#emailType#" 
    bcc="#bcc#"
>
<cfmailparam file="D:\Production_www4\uploads\11\WENS Crisis Overview - Healthcare-OPT.pdf" disposition="attachment" type="application/PDF">
```

But the problem is it does come properly, but just a generic name PDF Document. PDF which if I got that I would never open.

Is there a way I can rename the filename?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: try something like this - <cfmailparam file="#FileName#" type="#ContentType#/#ContentSubType#;name=""#FileName#""">

Comment: Adobe added support for it in CF2016 (CF10 is eol'd). For CF10, try specifying the file name in the `disposition` attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782066/changing-filename-of-attachment-in-cfmail